# testHarness ListState TTL not getting applied on Flink 1.8.2

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am testing a window function which has a listState, with TTL enabled.

Snippet of window function:

```java
public class CustomWindowFunction extends ProcessWindowFunction<InputPOJO, OutputPOJO, String, TimeWindow> {

  ...

  @Override
  public void open(Configuration config) {
    StateTtlConfig ttlConfig =
        StateTtlConfig.newBuilder(listStateTTl)
            .setUpdateType(StateTtlConfig.UpdateType.OnCreateAndWrite)
            .setStateVisibility(StateTtlConfig.StateVisibility.NeverReturnExpired) // NOTE: NeverReturnExpired
            .build();
    listStateDescriptor =  new ListStateDescriptor<>("unprocessedItems", InputPOJO.class);
    listStateDescriptor.enableTimeToLive(ttlConfig);
  }

  @Override
  public void process( String key, Context context, Iterable<InputPOJO> windowElements, Collector<OutputPOJO> out) throws Exception {

        ListState<InputPOJO> listState = getRuntimeContext().getListState(listStateDescriptor);

        ....

        Iterator<InputPOJO> iterator;

        // Getting unexpired listStateItems for computation.
        iterator = listState.get().iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            InputPOJO listStateInput = iterator.next();
            System.out.println("There are unexpired elements in listState");

            /** Business Logic to compute result using the unexpired values in listState**/
        }


        /** Business Logic to compute result using the current window elements.*/

        // Adding unProcessed WindowElements to ListState(with TTL)
        // NOTE: processed WindowElements are removed manually.
        iterator = windowElements.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println("unProcessed Item added to ListState.")
            InputPOJO unprocessedItem = iterator.next();
            listState.add(unprocessedItem); // This part gets executed for listStateInput1
        }

    }
    ....
}
```

I am using `testHarness` to perform the integration test. I am testing the listState item count when the TTL for the listState is expired. Below is my test function snippet.

**NOTE:**

1. There is a custom allowedLateness which is implemented using a custom Timer.

```java
private OneInputStreamOperatorTestHarness<InputPOJO, OutputPOJO> testHarness;

private CustomWindowFunction customWindowFunction;

@Before
public void setup_testHarness() throws Exception {

    KeySelector<InputPOJO, String> keySelector = InputPOJO::getKey;

    TypeInformation<InputPOJO> STRING_INT_TUPLE = TypeInformation.of(new TypeHint<InputPOJO>() {}); // Any suggestion ?

    ListStateDescriptor<InputPOJO> stateDesc = new ListStateDescriptor<>("window-contents", STRING_INT_TUPLE.createSerializer(new ExecutionConfig())); // Any suggestion ?

    /**
     * Creating windowOperator for the below function
     *
     * <pre>
     *
     *      DataStream<OutputPOJO> OutputPOJOStream =
     *         inputPOJOStream
     *             .keyBy(InputPOJO::getKey)
     *             .window(ProcessingTimeSessionWindows.withGap(Time.seconds(triggerMaximumTimeoutSeconds)))
     *             .trigger(new CustomTrigger(triggerAllowedLatenessMillis))
     *             .process(new CustomWindowFunction(windowListStateTtlMillis));
     * </pre>
     */
    customWindowFunction = new CustomWindowFunction(secondsToMillis(windowListStateTtlMillis));

    WindowOperator<String, InputPOJO, Iterable<InputPOJO>, OutputPOJO, TimeWindow>
        operator =
            new WindowOperator<>(
                // setting .window(ProcessingTimeSessionWindows.withGap(maxTimeout))
                ProcessingTimeSessionWindows.withGap(Time.seconds(triggerMaximumTimeoutSeconds)),
                new TimeWindow.Serializer(),
                // setting .keyBy(InputPOJO::getKey)
                keySelector,
                BasicTypeInfo.STRING_TYPE_INFO.createSerializer(new ExecutionConfig()),
                stateDesc,
                // setting  .process(new CustomWindowFunction(windowListStateTtlMillis))
                new InternalIterableProcessWindowFunction<>(customWindowFunction),
                // setting .trigger(new CustomTrigger(allowedLateness))
                new CustomTrigger(secondsToMillis(allowedLatenessSeconds)),
                0,
                null);

    // Creating testHarness for window operator
    testHarness = new KeyedOneInputStreamOperatorTestHarness<>(operator, keySelector, BasicTypeInfo.STRING_TYPE_INFO);

    // Setup and Open  Test Harness
    testHarness.setup();

    testHarness.open();
}

@Test
public void test_listStateTtl_exclusion() throws Exception {

    int allowedLatenessSeconds = 3;
    int listStateTTL = 10;

    //1. Arrange
    InputPOJO listStateInput1 = new InputPOJO(1,"Arjun");
    InputPOJO listStateInput2 = new InputPOJO(2,"Arun");


    // 2. Act
    // listStateInput1 comes at 1 sec
    testHarness.setProcessingTime(secondsToMillis(1));
    testHarness.processElement(new StreamRecord<>(listStateInput1));


    // Setting current processing time to  1 + 3 = 4 > allowedLateness.
    // Window.process() is called, and window is purged (FIRE_AND_PURGE)
    // Expectation: listStateInput1 is put into listState with TTL (10 secs), before process() ends.
    testHarness.setProcessingTime(secondsToMillis(4));

    // Setting processing time after listStateTTL, ie 4 + listStateTTL(10) + 1 = 15
    // Expectation: listStateInput1 is evicted from the listState  (Fails)
    testHarness.setProcessingTime(secondsToMillis(15));

    // Using sleep(), the listStateTTL is getting applied to listState and listStateInput1 is evicted (Pass)
    //Thread.sleep(secondsToMillis(15))

    //Passing listStateInput2 to the test Harness
    testHarness.setProcessingTime(secondsToMillis(16));
    testHarness.processElement(new StreamRecord<>(listStateInput2));


    // Setting processing time after allowedLateness = 16 + 3 + 1 = 20
    testHarness.setProcessingTime(secondsToMillis(20));

    // 3. Assert
     List<StreamRecord<? extends T>> streamRecords = testHarness.extractOutputStreamRecords();
     // Expectation: streamRecords will only contain listStateInput2, since listStateInput1 was evicted.
     // Actual: Getting both listStateInput1 & listStateInput2 in the output.
}
```

I noticed that TTL is not getting applied by setting processing time. When I tried the same function with Thread.sleep(TTL), the result was as expected.

1. Is listState TTL using system time for eviction (with testHarness)?
2. Is there any way to test listStateTTL using testHarness?

Comment: Hi @DominikWosiński. Did you mean window function descriptor definition? It is already provided in the `open()` of `CustomWindowFunction`.

Comment: If it is about the windowOperator definition, I have added it now in `setup_testHarness()`

Answer (score 0):

TTL test should by the following way

```
 @Test
public void testSetTtlTimeProvider() throws Exception {
    AbstractStreamOperator<Integer> operator = new AbstractStreamOperator<Integer>() {};
    try (AbstractStreamOperatorTestHarness<Integer> result =
            new AbstractStreamOperatorTestHarness<>(operator, 1, 1, 0)) {

        result.config.setStateKeySerializer(IntSerializer.INSTANCE);
        result.config.serializeAllConfigs();

        Time timeToLive = Time.hours(1);
        result.initializeState(OperatorSubtaskState.builder().build());
        result.open();

        ValueStateDescriptor<Integer> stateDescriptor =
                new ValueStateDescriptor<>("test", IntSerializer.INSTANCE);
        stateDescriptor.enableTimeToLive(StateTtlConfig.newBuilder(timeToLive).build());
        KeyedStateBackend<Integer> keyedStateBackend = operator.getKeyedStateBackend();
        ValueState<Integer> state =
                keyedStateBackend.getPartitionedState(
                        VoidNamespace.INSTANCE,
                        VoidNamespaceSerializer.INSTANCE,
                        stateDescriptor);

        int expectedValue = 42;
        keyedStateBackend.setCurrentKey(1);
        result.setStateTtlProcessingTime(0L);
        state.update(expectedValue);
        Assert.assertEquals(expectedValue, (int) state.value());
        result.setStateTtlProcessingTime(timeToLive.toMilliseconds() + 1);
        Assert.assertNull(state.value());
    }
}
```